# difference of member when accessing by this pointer and member pointer of itself (simple QT example question)

Tags: c++, qt

I've been following a simple QT tutorial and came up with a weird noob question.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F56fSKoNCtk&list=PLS1QulWo1RIZiBcTr5urECberTITj7gjA&index=5

this is the tutorial.

Here's the my_window.h

```
#ifndef MY_WINDOW_H
#define MY_WINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MyWindow;
}

class MyWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MyWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MyWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MY_WINDOW_H
```

and my_window.cpp.

```
#include "my_window.h"
#include "ui_mywindow.h"

MyWindow::MyWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MyWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->horizontalSlider,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
            ui->progressBar,SLOT(setValue(int)));
}

MyWindow::~MyWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MyWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   ui->label->setText("Clicked!");
}

void MyWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    ui->label->setText("Why...?");
}
```

In my_window.cpp, the definition of the constructor,
it does the tasks via the member pointer, 'ui' which is a pointer of 'MyWindow type' instance.
I thought 'this' pointer is also a 'MyWindow' class type pointer so i thought i can access the horizontalSlider and progressBar with this pointer too.
But i couldn't.

what makes the difference between two of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class `MyWindow` that you define in `my_window.h` and implement in `my_window.cpp` is `::MyWindow`. Then you have `::Ui::MyWindow` which is a totally separate class, and is defined and implemented in auto-generated files by Qt and the Qt tools.

You can have many symbols with the same name, as long as they are defined in different *scopes*. These symbols can even be different types, like one could be a class, one could be a variable, one could be a function, etc.